# is there anyway getting location when app is killed?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am trying get location in background, I got coordinates when application goes background, but When I kill application (swipes up from home in app) getting location is terminated, when Application is killed can I getting location in ios? is there anyway getting location when app is killed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is there anyway getting location when app is killed?

No.

First of all, if the app is killed, it is not running, and if it isn't running, it cannot do anything.

Second, even though you *can* have the *system* monitor location on the app's behalf even when the app is *not* running, you *can't* do that if the app has been *killed by the user.* This a deliberate design decision by Apple. If the user kills the app, the system assumes that all activity related to the app is considered undesirable, so related background processes such as location monitoring are cancelled too.

Comment: but When kill WhatsApp it continues sending notifications, does apple only allow notifications even if the app is terminated

Comment: But that is not what you asked about. You asked about location.

Comment: yes, i know but I am trying to get solution, if I listen notification when app is killed, can I send last location in notification receiver?

Comment: @Diego It's important to understand that notifications are displayed by iOS. If they have custom UI, the system calls the app's extension, but not the app itself. If the app was killed, it's only launched if the user taps the notification. Background processing of notifications doesn't work if the app was killed either.

Comment: but When I kill WhatsApp, notifications is working, how is it works? @lazarevzubov

Comment: @Diego it's APNs, kind of server-side. You should take a look first.

Comment: @son if I use Firebase notification and killed application by the user , is it works notification

Comment: @Diego I think I've explained it in brief in my previous comment: Notifications are shown by iOS, not your app. If you want to learn more details about it, Apple has plenty of documentation on the topic. As for Firebase, internally, it also sends notifications to Apple's server first, then the latter sends the notification to specific devices where iOS displays them.